# How to efficiently retrieve groups of objects from activerecord with a single SQL query?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I have a table `products` which has a `product_type_code` column on it. What I'd like to do is retrieve different numbers of objects based on this column (eg.: 3 products with `product_type_code = 'fridge'`, 6 products with `product_type_code = 'car'`, 9 products with `product_type_code = 'house'`, etc.).

I know I can do like this:

```
fridges = Product.where(product_type_code: 'fridge').limit(3)
houses = Product.where(product_type_code: 'house').limit(9)
[...]
```

And even create a scope like this:

```
# app/models/product.rb

scope :by_product_type_code, -> (material) { where(product_type_code: product_type_code) }
```

However, this is not efficient since I go to the database 3 times, if I'm not wrong. What I'd like to do is something like:

```
scope :by_product_type_code, -> (hash) { some_method(hash) }
```

where hash is: `{ fridge: 3, car: 6, house: 9 }`

and get an ActiveRecord_Relation containing 3 fridges, 6 cars and 9 houses.

How can I do that efficiently?

Comment: You want those numbers, or real records?

Comment: You can combine `group by`, `order` and `limit` but it won't be a Rails-only solution

Comment: @ArupRakshit I want the real records

Comment: @MrYoshiji It doesn't have to be a Rails-only solution. Of course, it would be really nice if it was, but since writting pure SQL is way more efficient than trusting any ORM to do it, I'm up to it! ;D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[@SebastianPalma](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5025116/sebastian-palma)'s answer is the best solution; however if you were looking for a more "railsy" fashion of generating this query you can use `arel` as follows:

```
scope :by_product_type_code, ->(h) { 
   products_table = self.arel_table
   query = h.map do |product_type,limit| 
     products_table.project(:id)
       .where(products_table[:product_type_code].eq(product_type))
       .take(limit)
   end.reduce do |scope1, scope2|
     Arel::Nodes::UnionAll.new(scope1,scope2)
   end 
   self.where(id: query)
end
```

This will result in the sub query being part of the where clause.

Or

```
scope :by_product_type_code, ->(h) { 
   products_table = self.arel_table
   query = h.map do |product_type,limit| 
     products_table.project(Arel.star)
       .where(products_table[:product_type_code].eq(product_type))
       .take(limit)
   end.reduce do |scope1, scope2|
     Arel::Nodes::UnionAll.new(scope1,scope2)
   end 
   sub_query = Arel::Nodes::As.new(query,products_table)
   self.from(sub_query)
end
```

This will result in the subquery being the source of the data.

Comment: Readability is very poor compared to SQL. But it is nice to watch and learn how an SQL can be converted to Arel. So +1. thanks.

Comment: @ArupRakshit I can agree that it takes some getting used to but I have found that the maintainability is far greater than raw SQL and the integration with AR works flawlessly. Additionally you get all the benefits of SQL escaping and type casting that arel natively provides.

Answer (score 6):

You can create a query using UNION ALL, which selects records having a specifc `product_type_code` and `limit` to use it with `find_by_sql`:

```
{ fridge: 3, car: 6, house: 9 }.map do |product_type_code, limit|
  "(SELECT *
   FROM products
   WHERE product_type_code = '#{product_type_code}'
   LIMIT #{limit})"
end.join(' UNION ALL ')
```

And you're gonna have a query like:

```
(SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_type_code = 'fridge'LIMIT 3)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_type_code = 'car'LIMIT 6)
UNION ALL
(SELECT * FROM products WHERE product_type_code = 'house'LIMIT 9)
```

Comment: I don't see any other better options than this `UNION ALL` technique.

Comment: Me neither. But let's keep waiting.

Comment: You could make it more "railsy" using `arel` but will result in the same query either way. Added an answer for edification purposes especially since rails 6 is cracking down on raw SQL.

Comment: I really appreciate the answer (and upvoted it), it solves my problem efficiently, thanks a lot! However I'll accept @engineersmnky since it's more "railsy" as he said haha.

Comment: No problemo, glad to help. Thanks!

Comment: To extend this answer, you could easily store this complex `select` `union`'ed into a `view`, then "face it" with a Rails read-only model for easy use in your Rails app.